# Playbook cannot work and other tests are normal

Tags: kubuntu, lubuntu, ansible

Ansible is installed at Ubuntu. I want to see output of cisco command "show ip interface brief" but it cannot work with some error message as below. All hosts and playbook info are listed in below picture.

There is no any issue to ping or ssh the router. Anyone can help to take a look at it? Thank you very much

[playbook-show-interface-router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maH28.png)

[playbook-show-interface-router2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy9f5.png)

```
kueve@ubuntu:~/playbook$ ansible -m ping cisco
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/kueve/inventory/ansible.cfg.save as an inventory source
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /home/kueve/inventory/hosts.save with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'all:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/kueve/inventory/hosts.save as an inventory source
192.168.1.24 | SUCCESS => { "changed": false, "ping": "pong"
```

Comment: Run the playbook with the option `'-vvvv' to enable connection debugging`. Post the details as a block `'>'` not as an image. Simplify the play. For testing the connection run single task [*ping*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/ping_module.html#ping-try-to-connect-to-host-verify-a-usable-python-and-return-pong-on-success).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Please see ping test, but -vvvv output is too big to post kueve@ubuntu:~/playbook$ ansible -m ping cisco
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/kueve/inventory/ansible.cfg.save as an inventory source
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/kueve/inventory/hosts.save with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'all:' supplied,
ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/kueve/inventory/hosts.save as an inventory source
192.168.1.24 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"

Comment: The connection is working ``SUCCESS => { "changed": false, "ping": "pong"}``. (Never put code into the comments.  Approve my edit and remote the comment.) Run the code with `-vvv` and analyze the error `not a valid RSA private key file`. Edit your question and put the details there. Remove the links and images. Try to create [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [issue of playbook via ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404325/issue-of-playbook-via-ubuntu)